# firebase.auth().currentUser returns null when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I added the function as you mentioned but when i login it shows this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'photo' of undefined
    at feed.page.ts:32
    at auth.esm.js:326
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at zone.js:896
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:502)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
    at timer (zone.js:2281)
```

If I refresh the page it says :

```
 getEvents() is not a function
```

Changes i made and still getting the error. It is wierd because when i login and redirect toe FeedPage i get error photo of undefined, if i refresh i get getEvents() is not e function.After i refresh the photo variable is null in the feed.html and cannot be binded to the ngModel and show the photo in avatar.

```
events: any[] = [];
  likes: any[] = [];
  pageSize = 10;
  cursor: any; // can be declared as DocumentSnapshot
  infiniteEvent: any;
  state: any;
  private photo = '';

  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController, private http: HttpClient, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        this.photo = user.photoURL;
        this.getEvents();
      } else {
        console.log('Not authenticated');
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
  }


  public async getEvents() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading events...'
    });

    loading.present();
    const query = firebase.firestore().collection('events').orderBy('created', 'desc').limit(this.pageSize);

    query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const changedDocs = snapshot.docChanges();

      changedDocs.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          // TODO
        }
        if (change.type === 'modified') {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
            if (this.events[i].id == change.doc.id) {
              this.events[i] = change.doc;
            }
          }
        }
        if (change.type === 'removed') {
          // TODO
        }
      })
    })

    query.get()
      .then((events) => {

        events.forEach((event) => {
          this.events.push(event);
        });

        loading.dismiss();

        if (events.size == 0) {
          this.cursor = 0;
        } else {
          this.cursor = this.events[this.events.length - 1]; // the last index of the collection
        }
        console.log(this.events);

      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: "Changes i made and still getting the error. " This is a completely different error. I answered it below too, but please limit yourself to one problem per post. If the error message is substantially different than before, it is likely a new problem (in the same use-case). Have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to isolate the problem.

Comment: I've written a blog post about the best practices for [responding to changes in the current user](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not set when your `Feed.ts` runs. This is expected, since the client may need to check with the server if the token is still valid, which is an asynchronous operation.

In cases like this, always use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener, as shown in the first snippet in the docs on [getting the current signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

So something like:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    ... code that uses the user's properties
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

**Edit**

Your new `getEvents() is not a function` error is caused by the fact that `this` has a different meaning inside a callback function that is declared as `function()`. The simplest solution here is use `=>` notation, which maintains the value of `this` inside the function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.photo = user.photoURL;
    this.getEvents();
  } else {
    console.log('Not authenticated');
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Note that the rest of your code already uses `=>` notation, which makes me suspect that you haven't been writing JavaScript all that long yet. I highly recommend taking a tutorial in callback function in JavaScript, as it'll save you a lot of time and questions) going forward.

Comment: i added that function, but where exacly do i have to add it? In constructor, or after that? The same problem ocurred

Comment: You'd add it anywhere where you need the current user, and can't be sure that the user is signed in already (which is almost everywhere).

Comment: The problem is i cant add it anywhere becuase there are some debugs errors.I have to add before dhe variable declarations because the code fails at finding the photoUrl.Can you show me where to implement it , in an example?

Comment: Any code that needs information about the currently signed in user, will need to be in your `onAuthStateChanged` callback.

Comment: Please edit your question to also show the code you now have based on my answer, and the exact error message+stack trace you get.

Comment: Is there any mechanism like `auth().getCurrentUser() : Promise<User | null>`, that will suspend until the token is checked in server, or return immedietly if it's already checked? I want to show progressbar until I'm sure that user is signed in or not. `auth().onAuthStateChanged()` just doesn't fit this scenario.

Comment: Nothing built in, but you could roll a `awaitAuthenticatedUser()` fairly easily with `onAuthStateChanged` and a promise. Give it a try, and if you're having a hard time getting it to work, post a new question with the code that you've tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh now i fully understand , and as exacly as you said i haven't been writing too much javascript code here, as i was watiching some tutoirals and adding some other things. I fixed the problem and also you helped me understand a basic but important thing. Thanks a lot for your time.